# Powershell passing switch parameter to self

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell script that calls itself (because stage 1 of the script is to load assemblies in the GAC so i need AppDomain refreshed). How do I pass a switch parameter to self. At the moment I am doing this:

```
if ($provisionsites -eq $true)
{
    powershell $currentDirectory/Deploy.ps1 -reload:$true -env:$env -provisionsites
}
else
{
    powershell $currentDirectory/Deploy.ps1 -reload:$true -env:$env
}
```

It seems too verbose to me. If i try this:

```
powershell $currentDirectory/Deploy.ps1 -reload:$true -env:$env -provisionsites:$provisionsites
```

It fails with :

> Cannot convert value "System.String" to type
>   "System.Management.Automat ion.SwitchParameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably call of `powershell.exe` is not needed at all. Replace it with the operator `&`, i.e. call the script in the same session and avoid parameter transformations and related issues. The issues are resolvable but better be avoided in the first place. That is, do

```
& $currentDirectory/Deploy.ps1 -reload:$true -env:$env -provisionsites:$provisionsites
```

---

As for the issues. `$provisionsites` is converted to a string (`True` or `False`, not `$true` or `$false`) before passing in the external application. Thus, the result actual arguments look like `-provisionsites:True`. Then in a new powershell session it passes such an argument to the script `Deploy.ps1`. It fails because strings `True` or `False` are not expected, a Boolean value is expected.

A possible workaround would be adding escaped `$`

```
powershell $currentDirectory/Deploy.ps1 ... -provisionsites:`$$provisionsites
```

But consider to remove the call of `powershell` and its issues.

Comment: SO using the & operator refreshes the App Domain as well? Is ti just a shortcut or are there differences?

Comment: `&` is not a shortcut for `powershell`. It's an operator "invoke a command", in a new scope if it is a script or a function (in contrast to the `.` operator == invoke in the same scope). In some cases it can be omitted but not in your case because the command itself is the result of an evaluated expression. As for the "refreshes the App Domain as well", I do not know what your Deploy.ps1 does. Actually, perhaps you still **have** to use a call via powershell which means starting a separate powershell process. That is why I started my answer with the word "Presumably", I was not sure.

Comment: I am deploying assemblies to the GAC, assemblies that I potentially reference in step 2 of the script hence why i need a new powershell process to refresh App Domain. Thanks for your answer it makes perfect sense